# ImageMagick - convert png(s) to animated gif rather than having separate multiple overlapping images

Tags: macos, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

Confuse as to what I'm doing wrong. I used the following command:

```
convert -loop 0 -delay 10 dog_cursor_24_1.png dog_cursor_24_2.png dog_cursor_24_3.png, dog_cursor_24_4.png, dog_cursor_24_5.png test.gif
```

Outputs a GIF image but upon viewing, the images are overlapping each other, which I do not want. Should look like a moving picture.

Answer (score 2):

In Imagemagick, you do not use commas. So remove them. Put -loop 0 before the output gif and add +repage after reading the pngs to remove any virtual canvas.

```
convert -delay 10 dog_cursor_24_1.png dog_cursor_24_2.png dog_cursor_24_3.png dog_cursor_24_4.png dog_cursor_24_5.png +repage -loop 0 test.gif
```

If that does not work, then post your animation. It may need a different -dispose method.